# Pure Css transition slide down panel not working

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make slideDown Menu on hover.So on hovering HButton3 i want to extend the height of AccomodationPanel so that the buttons inside it display becasue the extend but nothing happens on hover it looks like its something in the position of the elements

HTML :

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Header" CssClass="header">
     <div  id="StayOpen" style="z-index:5;">
                   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Hbutton3" CssClass="HButton" >                
                   </asp:LinkButton>

                   <div id="AccomodationPanel" style ="position:fixed;left:60vw;width:20vw;top:10vh;background-color:#333333;height:0px;overflow:hidden;z-index:10;"  >

                       <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="StayOpen1" CssClass="StayOpen" OnClick="StayOpen1_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
                       <br />
                         <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="StayOpen2" CssClass="StayOpen" OnClick="StayOpen2_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
                        <br />
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="StayOpen3" CssClass="StayOpen" OnClick="StayOpen3_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>

         </div>
     </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

CSS:

```
 .HButton {
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    text-anchor:middle;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:25px;
    left:20vw;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    top:2vh;
    font-family:'Arial Unicode MS';
    z-index:3;
    }        
.header {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100vw;
height:10vh;
background-color:#333333;
-moz-box-shadow:    0 0 3px 1px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow:  0 0 3px 1px black;
  box-shadow:          0 0 3px 1px black;

z-index:4;
position:fixed !important;
position:absolute;
}
```

hovering css:

```
#StayOpen:hover ~ #AccomodationPanel {

         height:300px;

}
```

Comment: Your selector seems to be wrong. Try `#StayOpen > #AccomodationPanel` as `#AccomodationPanel` is a child of `#StayOpen`, not a sibling.

Comment: #StayOpen:hover > #AccomodationPanel {
height:300px;
}

same thing not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height of `#StayOpen` is `0px`. Also you have to check [CSS rule priorities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Your code might look like this:

```
#StayOpen {
    height: 100%;
}
#StayOpen:hover #AccomodationPanel {
    height:300px !important;
}
```

Look at [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/27Lvo9ot/).

**Transition**

In your question you've mentioned about transition. You can add it in `#AccomodationPanel` ([updated example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/27Lvo9ot/2/)):

```
#AccomodationPanel {
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
    transition: height 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because inline style has priority over stylesheet styles. If you move your inline style to the stylesheet it's working as expected.

```
#AccomodationPanel {
    position:fixed;
    left:60vw;
    width:20vw;
    top:10vh;
    background-color:#333333;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:10;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/w0gwu4gm/)

Comment: I noticed you're using single line code blocks in a lot of your answers, where you really should be using multi-line code blocks (which are more readable and clean). I corrected several of your answers, including this one... Just so you know, you can create multiline code-blocks either (1) by selecting all lines of your code and pressing the "code" button in the editor, or (2) just by indenting your code by exactly 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think because your `#AccomodationPanel` has inline style that set `height` to `0px` and your css wont won. To win the `inline` styles, you can add `!important` to your css. Example:

```
#StayOpen:hover #AccomodationPanel {
    height:300px !important;
}
```